# How to delay "new function" from caching parameters on compilation, wait until it is being used

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-redshift

I am trying to start a [red-shift client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-redshift). However, when I try to load the environment variables which I am receiving from AWS Secret Manager first, it seems to load the following code/ cache the following parameters for the connection which results in an error since everything is 'undefined'.

```
const client = {
        user: process.env.user,
        password: process.env.pass,
        database: process.env.db,
        port: process.env.port,
        host: process.env.host
  };


const redshiftClient = new redshift(client, {rawConnection: false})
```

After the secrets have loaded, I am calling the redshiftClient with a function in the same script:

```
retrieveData() {
        return redshiftClient.query(`SELECT * 
            FROM cit.rules`, 
        {raw: true}, function(err, data){
            if(err) console.error(err);
            else {
                return data;
            }
        });
    }
```

I am not sure why it is getting called/cached right away before the requests are completed. Shouldn't that only happen after I call redshiftClient for the first time? What can I do to ensure my environment variables have loaded from the secretmanager and that I can still access redshiftClient.query?

Comment: So, *after* you do `new redshift(...)` but *before* you do `retrieveData`, `process.env...` gets its values from secret manager…?!

Comment: I am importing this module at the top of the script so I am assuming it is getting called before my secret manager is getting called. Maybe my answer below of how I fixed it will give you some idea of the run time. I am definitely open to better answers as I feel mine is just a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Since it is creating a new object, I was able to edit the password value before calling it by doing the following:

`redshiftClient.config.password = process.env.pass;`

I got to this answer by showing the contents of redshiftClient object with console.log and then seeing where the password was being stored.

This updates the value before my query is called. I'm sure there is a better way to do this but it is the workaround I was able to find.